# Tumblr API Jquery load image

Tags: javascript, jquery, draw, tumblr, api-design

I'd like to use the tumblr API with JS to draw the latest posted images to blog with mouse movement.

I've successfully got it drawing HTML image links but need some help implementing the API images. 
I've made a JSfiddle - I'm looking to replace the two tree images with the API loaded images, the aim is to have all of the API images (20) to draw on with the mouse movement. In the fiddle I have loaded the API images onto the page to check they are being received properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hevering123/xpvt214o/721906/

```js
// Tumblr API load -
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/typophile.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=sNCvOfqUTzUJzBOViCbYfkaGeQaFAS4Q4XNtHMu8YPo6No3OiY",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(posts){
      var postings = posts.response.posts;
      var text = '';
      for (var i in postings) {
        var p = postings[i]; 
        var type = p.type; 
        if(type == 'photo'){
            text += '<li><a href='+p.post_url+' target="_blank"><img src=' + p.photos[0].original_size.url +'></a></li>';
        }else if(type == 'text'){
                text += '<li>' +p.body+ '</li>';
        }else{ 
            text += '<li>Some other post type<li>'; 
        }
        console.log(type);
      }
      $('ul').append(text);
    }
});
```

Below is the draw image JS

```js
// draw image function
function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
    drawStuff()
}
function drawStuff() {
    function e() {
        new Date - a < p ? setTimeout(e, p) : (g = !1,
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height))
    }
// It's the below code specifically that I'm completely stuck with, how do I replace the local img pngs with the correct JS to call in the API tumblr images
    var i = ["https://www.fast-growing-trees.com/images/P/Sawtooth-Oak_450_a.jpg", "https://cdn.allbirds.com/image/fetch/q_auto,f_auto/q_auto,f_auto,b_rgb:fff,w_500/https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1104/4168/files/PDP_Plant_1_1.png%3Fv%3D1520805044" ] 
      , t = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
      , n = 80
      , _ = 0;
    isMobile && (n = 1);
    var a, g = !1, p = 2500;
    jQuery("#bg-canvas").on("mousemove touchend", function(s) {
        if (jQuery(".move").hide(),
        a = new Date,
        g === !1 && (g = !0,
        setTimeout(e, p)),
        s.pageX - t.x > n || s.pageX - t.x < -n || s.pageY - t.y > n || s.pageY - t.y < -n) {
            t.x = s.pageX,
            t.y = s.pageY;
            var o = new Image;
            o.onload = function() {
                var e = .5 * this.width
                  , i = .5 * this.height;
                context.drawImage(o, s.pageX - e, s.pageY - i)
            }
            ,
            _ < i.length - 1 ? (_++,
            o.src = i[_]) : (_ = 0,
            o.src = i[_])
        }
    }),
    jQuery("header p")({
    })
}
var MD = [].join("\n");
console.log(MD, "color: white; background-color: black;");
var isMobile = !1;
"ontouchstart"in document.documentElement && (jQuery(".move").text("tap"),
isMobile = !0);
var canvas = document.getElementById("bg-canvas")
  , context = canvas.getContext("2d");
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, !1),
resizeCanvas();
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: What specifically are you stuck with? What have you tried to unstuck?

Comment: I'm stuck with how to combine the tumblr API with the first JS to load the latest 16 photo posts from tumblr. As these are images gathered using the API I can't use "img/11.jpg" to load them in the JS. I've tried a bunch of different options but have limited coding skills, just playing around and learning at the moment!

Comment: You are right, instead of a predefined array, you now have `data.response.posts.photos` as your links array

Comment: Hi Luca, I've updated the main post with some more of my workings! Still haven't been able to crack it but hopefully further in the right direction. I've also made a JS fiddle that shows my problem a little better!

Comment: Define an empty array above your jquery ajax call. `var arrImage = []`. when you loop through the tumblr API images you can push each item to the array. `arrImage.push(p.photos[0].original_size.url);` then you should be able to pass this populated array to your `drawStuff()` function.